# Fetch JSON data from API Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

So I have been working on a mini project however I can't seem to fetch data from the JSON file in JavaScript.

I have the data displayed in the console, however if I want to print out the first array I get the value 'undefined' 
[image: Below is a screenshot of the console]

Here is my script.js file:

```
var URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=f1d314280284e94ff7d1feeed7d44fdf&language=en-US&page=1";

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;

ourRequest.open('GET', URL);

ourRequest.onload = function (){

var data = ourRequest.responseText;

var ourData=JSON.parse(data);

console.log(ourData); // this line of code displays the full list of movies

console.log(ourData[0]); // this line displays undefined
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that your image is from that code? I just did a `GET` on that endpoint and got the following object back: `{page: 1, total_results: 19821, total_pages: 992, results: Array(20)}`. Your image is identical to the value of the `results` property. Try `ourData.results[0]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function I wrote. It is in use for the graphs on my mining pool so you can see it in action at [metaverse.farm](https://metaverse.farm). It will automatically retry every 10 seconds if it is unsuccesful.

```
function getJsonData(url, callback) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    let timer = setTimeout(function() {
        getJsonData(url, callback);
    }, 10000);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            return callback(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
        }
    }
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.send();
}
```

Just call it like so:

```
var jsonUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=f1d314280284e94ff7d1feeed7d44fdf&language=en-US&page=1";
var myData;
getJsonData(jsonUrl, function(data) {
    myData = data;
});
```

And then all you need is:

```
console.log(myData.results[0]);
```

Output:

```
{vote_count: 7552, id: 299536, video: false, vote_average: 8.3, title: "Avengers: Infinity War", …}
```

You can even do:

```
var jsonUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=f1d314280284e94ff7d1feeed7d44fdf&language=en-US&page=1";
getJsonData(jsonUrl, function(data) {
    data.results[0].title = "WOOOOOOOOHOOOOOOOO!";
    console.log(data.results[0]);
});
```

Output:

```
{vote_count: 7552, id: 299536, video: false, vote_average: 8.3, title: "WOOOOOOOOHOOOOOOOO!", …}
```

If you combine it with a function like so, you have an asynchronous JSON loader which doesn't stop the browser doing other things:

```
var myData;
loader = $('.loader');

async function refreshData() {
    loader.show();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getJsonData(jsonUrl, function(data) {
            // Once the data is loaded...
            myData = data;
            insertData();
            loader.hide();
        });
    });
}
```